# How to wrap Ecto hstore field to get translations automatically?

Tags: internationalization, elixir, gettext, phoenix-framework, ecto

There is a lot of gems in Ruby to do what I would like in Elixir: [globalize](https://github.com/globalize/globalize), [multilang-hstore](https://github.com/bithavoc/multilang-hstore), [hstore_translate](https://github.com/Leadformance/hstore_translate)

How to automate e.g. using `Gettext.get_locale` retrieving translation according to current locale from hstore field? For example if I get it by related Post by `post.tags`, tags will contain a list of strings in case of locale is :en: `"tags: ["climbing", "ski"]"` instead of `"tags":[{"name":{"pl":"narty","en":"ski"}},{"name":{"pl":"wspinaczka","en":"climbing"}}]`? How to handle fallbacks with Gettext?

```
defmodule Myapp.Tag do
  use Myapp.Web, :model

  schema "tags" do
    field :name, :map
    belongs_to :post, Myapp.Post
    timestamps
  end

  def match(query, q) do
      from tag in query,
    where: fragment("?->>? ILIKE ?", tag.name, "en", ^(String.downcase(q) <> "%"))
  end
end

defmodule Myapp.TagController do
  use Myapp.Web, :controller
  alias Myapp.Tag

  def search(conn, %{"q" => q}) do
    tags = Tag |> Tag.match(q) |> Repo.all
    render(conn, "options.json", tags: tags)
  end
end

defmodule Myapp.TagView do
  use Myapp.Web, :view

  def render("options.json", %{tags: tags}) do
    %{options: render_many(tags, Myapp.TagView, "option.json")}
  end
  def render("option.json", %{tag: tag}) do
    %{id: tag.id,
      value: tag.name["en"],
      label: tag.name["en"]}
  end
end

defmodule Myapp.PostView do
  use Myapp.Web, :view

  def render("posts.json", %{posts: posts}) do
    %{data: render_many(posts, Myapp.PostView, "post.json")}
  end
  def render("post.json", %{post: post}) do
    %{id: post.id,
      title: post.title,
      tags: post.tags} # <= how to get translated keys
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gettext.get_locale Myapp.Gettext` should return according locale. When getting value from map, you can set the default value. For example:

```
Map.get(map, key, default)
```

So you can define function like:

```
defp translated_tag_name(tag, default_lang) do
  current_lang = Gettext.get_locale Myapp.Gettext
  Map.get(tag.name, current_lang, Map.get(tag.name[default_lang])
end
```

You do the fallback manually, but it is easy to make it work with any map.

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me yet how to translate all keys in list if I will get them in Myapp.PostView render function, through related `post.tags`? Could I do it automatically by default for each tags extraction without I suppose pipe operator?

Comment: If you want apply some operation to a list of elements, you can use map. `Enum.map(list, translate_key)`. You can add function to your model. that does the translation after retrieving stuff from Ecto and use it in your view.